# what to use instead of nodeSet

Tags: java, nodelist

I have a function where i need to compile a NodeList, it needs to use NodeList as I also use xpath to generate a NodeList and process the result.

my code is

```
NodeSet nodes = new NodeSet();

NodeList children = mainElement.getChildNodes();
for(int i=0;i<children.getLength();i++){
    Node child = children.item(i);
    if(nodeName==null || child.getNodeName().equals(nodeName)){
        if(attName==null){
            //if not att name then all nodes
            nodes.addNode(child);
        }
    }
}
```

I could write my own class, but I would have thought there would already be something available for this purpose?

NOTE if you are going to mark down kindly say why in comments, so I can correct in future.

Comment: I happy with how i do it i just need to return a NodeList, but NodeSet is marked as could be removed any time and should not be relied upon.

I believe it is possible via xpath, but I cannot figure out how to get the current xpath from a node, to then use xpath to search below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed also use XPath to build your result.
As it stands, your code grabs "all nodes of name `nodeName` that are direct children of the `mainElement` node".

Which translates to the `nodeName` XPath expression, if it is evaluated in the context of the `mainElement`. Which is simple enough to do :

```
XPath nodeNameXPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile(nodeName)
NodeList result = (NodeList) nodeNameXPath.eval(mainElement, XPathConstants.NODESET)
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps life is better if you just do this in Java 8:

```
IntStream.range(0, children.getLength())
    .map(children::item)
    .filter(child -> child.getNodeName().equals(nodeName))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I guess a reason for there not to be a framework method for doing this sort of thing is that the traversal each consumer wishes to do might be radically different.

Comment: im using java 7, so this wont help for now, but does this return a NodeList?
All I want really is the object to use instead of NodeSet to get a NodeList